# Modify pandas dataframe values based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample of the data that I have.

```
    Label | Time
    A     | 1.42
    A     | 1.42
    C     | 2.21
    C     | 2.24
    C     | 2.24
    A     | 2.30
```

I want to modify the time for only the rows with the Label 'A'.

i.e. apply a function such as

time=time+adjustment for each row that has a Label 'A' to modify its time.

Is it possible to use df.apply to do this or is there any other way like using df.iterrows or df.itertuples ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Label=='A', 'Time'] += adjustment
```

[Pandas boolean indexing documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)